# converting timestamp state event logs to runtime in R data.table

Tags: r, timestamp, runtime, data.table

I have large data set of logged timestamps corresponding to state changes (e.g., light switch flips) that look like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
foo <- 
  data.table(ts = ymd_hms("2013-01-01 01:00:01",
                          "2013-01-01 05:34:34",
                          "2013-01-02 14:12:12",
                          "2013-01-02 20:01:00",
                          "2013-01-02 23:01:00",
                          "2013-01-03 03:00:00",
                          "2013-05-04 05:00:00"),
             state = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0) )
```

And I'm trying to (1) convert the history of state logs into run-times in seconds, and (2) convert these into daily cumulative run-times. Most (but not all) of the time, consecutive logged state values alternate. This is a kludgy start, but it falls a little short.

```
foo[, dif:=diff(ts)]
foo[state==1][, list(runtime = sum(dif)), .(floor_date(ts, "day"))]
```

In particular, when the state is "on" during a period that crosses midnight, this approach isn't smart enough to split things up, and incorrectly reports runtime longer than one day. Also, using `diff` is not so intelligent either, since it will make mistakes if there are consecutive identical states or `NAs`.

Any suggestions that will correctly resolve runtime that are still fast and efficient for large data sets?

Comment: How do you wish to handle events where the state has consecutive identical values? how should the run times be calculated then?

Comment: If there are consecutive state values (e.g. `state = c(1, 1, 1)`, these should all be considered the same run period since the state never really changed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  I played around with different starting values of `foo` but there could still be some edges cases I didn't factor in .  One thing that you will need to take note of is if your real data has a timezone that accepts daylight savings time then this will break when making the data.table with all dates.  You can workaround that by doing a `force_tz` to UTC or GMT first (you can change it back later).  On the other hand if you need to account for a 25 hour or 23 hour day then you'll need to strategically change them back to your timezone.

```
#I'm using devel version of data.table which includes shift function for leading/lagging variables
foo[,(paste0("next",names(foo))):=shift(.SD,1,0,"lead")]
#shift with fill=NA produced an error for some reason this is workaround
foo[nrow(foo),`:=`(nextts=NA,nextstate=NA)]
#make data.table with every date from min ts to max ts
complete<-data.table(datestamp=seq(from=floor_date(foo[,min(ts)],unit="day"),to=ceiling_date(foo[,max(ts)],unit="day"),by="days"))
#make column for end of day
complete[,enddate:=datestamp+hours(23)+minutes(59)+seconds(59.999)]
#set keys and then do overlapping join
setkey(foo,ts,nextts)
setkey(complete,datestamp,enddate)
overlap<-foverlaps(foo[state==1],complete,type="any")
#compute run time for each row
overlap[,runtime:=as.numeric(difftime(pmin(datestamp+days(1),nextts),pmax(datestamp,ts),units="secs"))]
#summarize down to seconds per day
overlap[,list(runtime=sum(runtime)),by=datestamp]
```

Comment: @Bryan does this do what you were looking for?